# PDO: Query does not produce the right results the first time

Tags: php, pdo

I have three queries on my login script.  One select query checks the users' credentials, another to update the last login, and the third one is a select query to see whether the user exists in another table, so if the user exists in the table, go some where.  If the user doesn't exist, go somewhere else.

The third query is the one is acting weird.   Below:

```
require_once '../includes/sessions.php';
//echo 'hello';
$employerlogindata = $_POST['employerlogindata'];

$data = json_decode($employerlogindata);

$employeremailfromjs = $data->employeremail;
$employerpasswordfromjs = $data->employerpassword;

//sanitization 
$employeremail = htmlentities($employeremailfromjs);
$employerpassword = htmlentities($employerpasswordfromjs);

//PHP validation rules 

$validflag = true;

function checkblanks($variable){
    if($variable == ''){
        $validflag = false;
        print_r('Empty Inputs.  Please try again.');
    }else {
        $variable = trim($variable);
        $variable = stripslashes($variable);
        return $variable;
    }
}
checkblanks($employeremail);
checkblanks($employerpassword);

if($validflag == false) {
 echo 'You have problematic entries.  Try again.';
} else {
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT EID AS dbeid, EMPLOYER_EMAIL AS dbemail, `PASSWORD` AS dbpwd, EMPLOYER_NAME AS dbcompanyname, LAST_LOGIN AS dblastlogin FROM userpwd WHERE EMPLOYER_EMAIL = :employeremail;";

        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(":employeremail", $employeremail);
        $query->execute(); 
        //echo "select statement successfully executed";
        //echo $sql;
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Error connecting to server: " . $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }
    //echo $query->rowCount();
    if ($query->rowCount() == 0){
        echo "Email/Password combo was not found in the system.";
    }else {
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        //print_r($result);

        $dbeid = $result->dbeid;
        $dbemail = $result->dbemail;
        $dbpwd = $result->dbpwd;
        $dbcompanyname = $result->dbcompanyname;
        $dblastlogin = $result->dblastlogin;

        //echo $dbeid;

        if(password_verify($employerpassword, $dbpwd)){
            try{
                $sql = "UPDATE userpwd SET LAST_LOGIN = NOW() WHERE EMPLOYER_EMAIL = :employeremail; ";
                $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $query->bindParam(":employeremail", $employeremail);
                $query->execute();

            }catch (PDOException $e){
                echo "Error connecting to server: " . $e->getMessage();
                die;
            }

            $_SESSION['EID'] = $dbeid;
            $_SESSION['EMPLOYER_EMAIL'] = $dbemail;
            $_SESSION['EMPLOYER_NAME'] = $dbcompanyname;
            $_SESSION['LAST_LOGIN'] = $dblastlogin;

            //echo "Logged in";             
        } else {
            echo "Email/Password combination is invalid. Please Try Again.";
        }
        try{
            $select = "SELECT EID from e_profile WHERE EID=:eid";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($select);
            $stmt->bindParam(":eid", $sessemployerid);

            $stmt->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Error connecting to server: " . $e->getMessage();
            die;
        }
        $res = $stmt->fetch();
        $eid = $res['EID'];
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
            echo "employerdashboard.php $eid $count";
            $stmt->closeCursor();
        } else if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0){
            echo "e_profile.php $eid $count";
            $stmt->closeCursor();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

After a set of login credential is successful, the script hits both the second and the third queries.  However, the third query takes on the results of the previous ran query. After a second click on the frontend with the same credentials, it produces the right results.

I thought maybe I could find the functionality of mysqli_free_result() in PDO's closeCursor, but that doesn't work.   I want it to produce the right result the first time.

Any clues as to why this is happening?

Comment: _Small Note_ `$validflag` will always be TRUE in your code. Look up variable scope in the manual

Comment: Your `checkblanks()` function returns a cleaned up variable, but you dont actually put that cleaned up varibale anywhere. Basically the `checkblanks()` achieves nothing other than taking up space in your code

Comment: I dont see anywhere where you set a value into `$sessemployerid` which you use in your last query ??

Comment: $sessemployerid is a global session variable, which is set in the session file included at the top . I'll fix the checkblanks function.

Comment: Except that you change the session value without pulling it back out `$_SESSION['EID'] = $dbeid;` ergo `$sessemployerid` could be out of sync with the value of `$dbeid` which would give inconsistent behavior.  At the very least you should have `global $sessemployerid =& $_SESSION['EID'];`  Although if it was me I would do away with the use of global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable is out of date (or at least that is my theory), as I said in the comments.

If you have

```
 global $sessemployerid = $_SESSION['EID'];
```

Then you do

```
 $_SESSION['EID'] = $dbeid;
```

Then you use `$sessemployerid` it will not be equal to `$_SESSION['EID'] = $dbeid`.  It will be equal to the previous value of the session when it was assigned, which may or may not be correct.  Probably on the first attempt it is wrong, then on subsequent attempts it is correct.

Just to lay it out a bit further:

```
//you assign $sessemployerid way up here
global $sessemployerid = $_SESSION['EID'];
...
//then you update the session
if(password_verify($employerpassword, $dbpwd)){
    try{
        $sql = "UPDATE userpwd SET LAST_LOGIN = NOW() WHERE EMPLOYER_EMAIL = :employeremail; ";
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(":employeremail", $employeremail);
        $query->execute();

    }catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "Error connecting to server: " . $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }

    $_SESSION['EID'] = $dbeid;  //<--- here you update the session but neglect $sessemployerid
    $_SESSION['EMPLOYER_EMAIL'] = $dbemail;
    $_SESSION['EMPLOYER_NAME'] = $dbcompanyname;
    $_SESSION['LAST_LOGIN'] = $dblastlogin;

    //echo "Logged in";             
} else {

 ....

 //then you use $sessemployerid, but it has a stale value (sometimes)
 $select = "SELECT EID from e_profile WHERE EID=:eid";
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($select);
 $stmt->bindParam(":eid", $sessemployerid);
```

To fix this you could use a reference assignment

```
global $sessemployerid =& $_SESSION['EID'];
```

This can be demonstrated by this simple code:

```
 $a = 1;
 $b =& $a;  //initial assignment, with reference  
 echo $b."\n";   
 $a = 2;  //change the value of $a

 echo $b;  //$b is auto-magically updated
```

See it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a4ba92e832cd8a492979d259b802b5dafc679c8)

Ouputs

```
1
2
```

If you do it this way (the "normal" way)

```
 $a = 1;
 $b = $a;  //initial assignment, normal
 echo $b."\n";   
 $a = 2;  //change the value of $a

 echo $b;  //$b is not updated
```

The output is

```
1
1
```

Alternatively you could simply update the global after changing the session's value:

```
if(password_verify($employerpassword, $dbpwd)){
    ...
    $_SESSION['LAST_LOGIN'] = $dblastlogin;
    global $sessemployerid = $_SESSION['EID'];
}else{
   ...
```

Because the value of `$sessemployerid` is out of sync with `$_SESSION['EID']` you will get inconstant behavior depending on if you had updated the session or not on a previous page attempt.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Your theory was right.  As a noob, I really appreciate that you took the time out of your day to break it down for me. I suspected something of a lag was happening, I just didn't know how to fix it.  Literally, right before I read your answer, I was going to unset($session['EID']), somehow save the old and new session eid in variables respectively, compare the two, then reset $session eid with the new session eid.  All of what I was about to do has been reduced to between a character to 1 line of code.  I come to SO for people like you, who can help me better understand code.  Thank you!